# Satisfiability and validity algorithms?

Tags: logic, algorithms, propositional-calculus

Any tips for how to go about this?

"Assume you have an algorithm A available, that when input with a propositional formula F, shows whether F is satisfiable or unsatisfiable.

Construct an algorithm B, which when input with a propositional formula F, showers whether F is valid or not valid."

Is this answer sufficient?:

|If F is valid, then A(F) = 1 for every valuation A. Hence A(¬F) =
B¬(A(F)) = B¬(1) = 0 for every valuation A, so ¬F is unsatisfiable."

Comment: Every valid formula is satisfiable, but there is something that separates valid formulas from other satisfiable ones. Namely, what can be said about their negations?

Comment: If a formula is valid, then its negation is also true... with satisfiable formulas this is not the case?

EDIT:  If F is valid, then NOT F is unsatisfiable.... So how do i then go forward with this to create an algorithm?

Comment: @JB28What you did doesn't seem right.You start by assuming $F$ is valid, but this is exactly what you want to find out. Let $B$ be the algorithm described as follows. As an input it receives a formula $F$, next it considers the negation ($\neg F$) of the given formula. Now use the algorithm $A$ on $\neg F$. Necessarily $\neg F$ is either satisfiable or unsatisfiable. Can you see how this helps you determine the validity of $F$?

Comment: Do I know what the algorithm A is? I'm confused.

Comment: @JB28 Yes, you do in a sense. "**Assume you have an algorithm A available**, that when input with a propositional formula F, shows whether F is satisfiable or unsatisfiable". In order to solve the problem, you don't need to actually know what it is. Think as if you have a lackey who knows the algorithm $A$ and your task is to "Construct an algorithm B, which when input with a propositional formula F, shows whether F is valid or not valid", by using whatever resources you have, including your lackey.